# How to extract .zip without zip folder name

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I want to download a .zip kernel from github, give it a name `kernel.zip` and extract its contents inside `kernel` folder. I did this:

```
mkdir kernel

wget -O kernel.zip https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/archive/surya-q-oss.zip -d kernel
#-o for overwrite all and -d for specifying where to put the files
unzip -o kernel.zip -d kernel
```

But it extracts to `kernel/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource-surya-q-oss/` instead of `kernel`.

Adding `-j` as said here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72838/unzip-file-contents-but-without-creating-archive-folder does not help, it simply places all files in the same place.

This solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1088207 involves knowing the archive name (`Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource-surya-q-oss` for this case), which I don't know

Comment: `mv kernel/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource-surya-q-oss .; rmdir kernel; mv Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource-surya-q-oss kernel`?

Comment: @Cyrus but this solution requires me to know the name `Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource-surya-q-oss`

Comment: `mv kernel/*/ foo & rmdir kernel & mv foo kernel`?

Comment: I guess @cyrus meant to use `&&`

Comment: @jhnc: Yes, I meant `&&`.